# Download a specific TFS build from the command line

Tags: tfs

Are there any TFS command-line utilities to download the .zip file for a specified build that exists in TFS? I know the most recent build can be found in the specified drop folder, but let's say I wanted to go back to some arbitrary build. I know I can do this in the web admin by selecting a build from the list, right clicking, and selecting "Open drop folder".

Is this possible from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but as it is scrabble through the API you can easily call it from PowerShell.

http://nakedalm.com/powershell-tfs-2013-api-1-get-tfscollection-and-tfs-services/

Here is an example of how that might be achieved. You will need to retrieve the IBuildDetail object...